# How do I convert timestamps to Julian time with millisecond precision using R?

Tags: r, timestamp, julian-date

I have a dataset that contains a column of timestamps. For example `"16-Feb-2015 17:41:36.666"` and `"16-Feb-2015 17:41:36.700"` are the elements in first two rows of this column. I am reading from a data-stream where a time-stamp is collected at a rate of 30 instances per second. How do I convert these time-stamp elements from this time-stamp to their corresponding Julian time with millisecond precision? R reads this column as a type factor.  I would like this to be a numeric.  I have tried using `as.character` and `as.numeric` but I sense there is a more specific way to hand time stamps.

Comment: Julian time (?) from which origin?

Comment: Would `as.Date` work? It would allow you to specify the format, and would get around treating a date like a factor or numeric.

Comment: `as.POSIXct(x, format  = "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%OS")` is the normal way to get millisecond precision (`%OS`)

Comment: Sorry forgot to specify origin.... 1/1/1970 is the desired origin. as.Date is something I looked into as well but it doesn't seem like it handles the time portion of the time-stamp... just the date.

Comment: Thanks Richard, that is somewhat helpful but now I need to get this POSIX object to be an integer.... The integer being the number of milliseconds since 00:00:00.00 01/01/1970 ..... perhaps I need to do it manually with a string splitting function and multiply accordingly.. I just wondered if there was already a function to do this.